# How to convert datasnap server from vcl app to windows service

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I have typical tcp/ip datasnap server app, I created as vcl forms (XE 8) and it connect to Firebird database on the same machine, now I want to convert it to run as windows service. How I can do that ?

Comment: See [Service Applications](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Service_Applications). Basically you need to remove all GUI parts.

Comment: Why do you have GUI at all?

Comment: @David Actually all of my services start with a test UI - but the backbone I have a ready-made shell to run as either/or - I implement a thread which can be run from either a UI or Service.

Comment: @JerryDodge That's a little off topic. What's important is the asker's scenario rather than yours.

Comment: Which is why it was in the form of a comment in response to your comment, which I thought was rather off-topic.

Comment: @Jerry If there's a good reason to have a gui then the user has significant work to do. My comment was on topic.

Comment: Perhaps there is no other reason as simply because one chooses Forms Application instead of Console Application or Service Application when creating the app with the DataSnap wizard? Especially as it is the default choice.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I like to use UI first for easy debug and test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a datasnap application as a Windows Service from File->New->Other->DataSnap Server->DataSnap Server; first wizard form, select "Service Application", complete the wizard amd migrate your non-UI code into that project.